# Combobox IsTextSearchEnabled = True validating entered text to check if it is present in Itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a very simple use case using `ComboBox` where `IsTextSearchEnabled`  property is `true` i.e. user can enter his text but I want to check if the entered text is present in the `itemsource`.

Is there a simple way to  this than binding Text property and validating entered text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe yes, this is the easiest way to do it, but this may not be very **mvvm** friendly, so basically what you need to do is :

1. Set the `Combobox`'s `IsTextSearchEnabled` and `IsEditable` to `true`,
2. Bind the `Combobox`'s `Text` Property to a `String` property in your codebehind,
3. each time the user enters text in the `combobox`, two possible senarios might occurs: either the entered text is in the `ItemSource`, in that case no further treatment is needed, the second possible scenario is that the entered text does't exist in the `ItemSource`, in that case you need to rollback and delete the last entered caracter,

here the xaml :

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name" x:Name="cbx"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Text="{Binding AddedText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>        
</Grid>
```

and here the properties and Model that needs to be added to the codebehind

```
 public class ListIte
 {
    public String Name { get; set; }        
 }
 //...
 private ObservableCollection<ListIte> _items =new ObservableCollection<ListIte>()
    {
        new ListIte()
        {
            Name = "Name"
        }, new ListIte()
        {
            Name = "Element"
        }, new ListIte()
        {
            Name = "Save"
        }, new ListIte()
        {
            Name = "Test"
        },
    } ;
    public ObservableCollection<ListIte> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_items == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private String _addedText ="" ;

    public String AddedText
    {
        get
        {
            return _addedText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_addedText == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.StartsWith(value))==null)
            {   
                //to get the Editable TextBox from the combobox
                var textBox = cbx.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cbx) as TextBox;
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.Text.Length - 1);
                textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
                return;
            }

            _addedText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```