# How to make combobox searchable by keywords

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image: i want to do like this]

Althrough i try searching,i can't find any.I'm using visual studio 2019.
Here's my combobox.

```
<ComboBox 
     Name="combo"
     IsEditable="True"
     SelectedValuePath="Id" 
     DisplayMemberPath="Name"                                
     ItemsSource="{Binding Data.CodeList, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" 

     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [IsTextSearchEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchenabled?view=netframework-4.8) property

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether TextSearch is enabled on the ItemsControl instance.

You can also check [Combobox IsTextSearchEnabled = True validating entered text to check if it is present in Itemsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359715/combobox-istextsearchenabled-true-validating-entered-text-to-check-if-it-is-pr) for checking against speciific values and rollback when they don't exist.

If you want to go before windows 10, then you'll have to use a custom control (effectivly create your own combobox.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I'm using MVVM and i got error when calling combobox name.what did i miss? 
var textBox = combo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combo) as TextBox;

Comment: I named my combox as combo but when i call from view model it's say "The name Combo does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @SirRufo - I updated with the correct link. Nice catch!

Comment: Is the combobox inside a template? I'd need the full code to check why it's out of scope.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975842/access-button-from-view-in-viewmodel-in-c-sharp You should not access the combobox directly in the ViewModel. It's moslty resolved with bindings